# Commenting is not available in this channel entry

Tags: comments

I did a new entry on my web site today. For some reason, when I look at the comment page, it says "Commenting is not available in this channel entry." And, no comment form shows up. I checked the entry options and "Allow Comments" is checked. Other entries on this site don't have this issue. Any idea why commenting is not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I checked the database, and this entry (in channel id 16) did have commenting turned on. But, there was another entry in a different channel (channel id 17) with an identical name/title, and it had commenting turned off. Somehow, EE got the two confused I guess. When I changed the name/title of the "other" entry (the one without commenting), then commenting on this entry started working.

Comment: I've had this same problem. And, it can become very troublesome when you have many channel entries and start duplicating titles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding: channel="my_channel", to your comment form tag where "my_channel" is the short name of your channel, and see if that works. It seems to work for me, but I'll need to create some duplicate named entries to further test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?
"cmt_commenting_has_expired" =>
"Commenting is not available in this weblog entry.",
I remember having the same problem  [at this website](http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/big-data-millennials-on-social-media-digging-a-little-deeper)  and it worked well.
I hope it will help you.